# Check if activity is alive on Gcm Intent Service

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to know if the user has the application opened, because when I receive a broadcast from GCM I create a notification with an intent to the application. When the user clicks on the notification, it will start a new intent to the main activity, putting the old main activity on the back stack, and then, when the user asks for a back navigation, it will close the intented activity and open (again for him) the last activity on stack.

Summarising:

Current activity on screen: **XActivity**

New notification with intent to XActivity.

User clicks on the notification, so the stack is **XActivity**, **XActivity**.

How could I detect if the XActivity is already shown and just send an extra content to it?

Thanks!

Comment: android manifest set the launch modes.. as single instance mode for clearance in the read android docs on launch modes http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the launch mode of your Activity to be `singleTop` and then start it with an intent that has the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. This will start the Activity if it is not running, otherwise the running instance will be used..

Comment: The running instance will receive the extra data from the intent?

Comment: Yes, you can override the `OnNewIntent()` method of the Activity to receive the data from the intent.

Comment: But how the cycle would be? first onCreate and then onNewIntent? (if the activity was dead on the intent call)

Comment: If the Activity was not running, OnCreate will be called but OnNewIntent will not be called. The opposite happens if the activity was already running.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare boolean variable: boolean isOnPause;

then override onResume() method, and make isOnPause = false;
override onPause() method and make isOnPause = true;

and check this variable before starting new Intent

Comment: What if your application is not running when the GCM message arrives?

Comment: Question started like this: "I want to know if the user has the application opened" and, I think my answer supplies solution for that. If application is opened, activity is definatly onResume(), and if it isn't opend, then onPause();